# Some structure tags not working after server move

Tags: structure, server-migration

Recently moved our development site onto the live hosting and now a few crucial structure tags are not working.

{structure:top:title}
{structure:child_ids}
{exp:structure:entries parent_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}

However the {exp:structure:nav} does work…

Any ideas? All works fine on our dev build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems extensions were somehow automatically disabled when we moved onto our live server, once turned on this tags worked again.